# Cannot access cloudera manager on port 7180

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, cloudera-manager

Installing Cloudera Manager on an AWS EC2 instance, following the official instruction:

> http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/manager/4-x/4-6-0/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_on_EC2.html

I successfully run the `.bin` package, but when I visit the `IP:7180` , the browser says my access has been denied...Why ...

---

I tried to confirm the status of cm server: `service cloudera-scm-server status`. At first it said

`cloudera-scm-server is dead and pid file exists`

The log file showed mentioned `"unknown host ip-10-0-0-110"` then I add a map between `ip-10-0-0-110` and the `EC2 instance **public** ip`. Then `restart` the scm-server service. It could run normally, but the IP:7180 remained unaccessable, saying `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I have uninstalled both the `iptables` and closed my windows `firewall`.

After a few minute, `cloudera-scm-server is dead and pid file exists` appeared again...

Using: `tail -40 /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.out`

> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-cloudera Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000794223000,
>   319201280, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
>
> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>    Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 319201280 bytes for committing reserved memory.
>    An error report file with more information is saved as:
>    /tmp/hs_err_pid5523.log

Comment: Check the firewall

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaReddy  Hi~~ I uninstalled `iptables`, but the access is still denied.. by the way, I used tcp protocol for the security group, is that the reason?

Answer (score 2):

What type of EC2 instance are you using?  The error is pretty descriptive and indicates that CM is unable to access memory. Maybe you are using an instance type with too little RAM.

Also - the docs you are referencing are out of date. The latest docs on deploying CDH5 in the cloud can be found here: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/director/latest/topics/director_get_started_aws.html

These docs also recommend using Cloudera Director which will simplify much of the deployment and configuration of your cluster.

Comment: That's it! I did not notice that the free instance only has 1g memory... I recreate an instance with more memory and can log into the cloudera manager now. But what confused me is now CM says the instance cannot receive signal from agent. I read the log, it says `unknown host.....`    I create the instance but it only has a public IP without a public DNS. Can you please tell me how to tackle this issue?

Comment: How many nodes besides CM are you using or have you deployed? what process did you go through to deploy these?  My suggestion would be to add nodes using their private IPs rather than public IPs.